# How to create a custom locale in 2019?

Tags: locale

In Ubuntu 18.04 I would like to create a new (custom) locale. Is this possible? There seem to be many older entries on how to do this but nothing current (none of the 'old' ways are working for me).

I would like to make a copy of en_US.utf8 and change the LC_TIME section to read like this

```
LC_TIME
copy "en_DK"
END LC_TIME
```

Assuming this is possible, here are my specific questions:

1) How should I name this new file I am creating? Does the name need to be in a specific format to be accepted? For example, is 'en_XX' acceptable? How about 'en_US@DK'?

2) How do I get this new created file to appear in the list when I run 'locale -a'?

3) How do I set this new file as the default locale via the CLI?

Comment: What have you already tried that didn't work? I would expect that creating a file in `/usr/share/i18n/locales`, writing an entry in `/etc/locale.gen` and running `sudo locale-gen` should do it.